# How to add data formatting and print data inside reacttable?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-table

Our application must be able to print all the data inside the react-table component of our application as a report. How can we achieve this function?

Comment: Elaborate your question, What you want? What you have? Add relevant pseudo code

Comment: we want to print individual data inside our react-table. @HarishKulkarni

Comment: What type of data you have?, what type of date that has to be formatted in?

Comment: It's all in string @HarishKulkarni... I just want to arrange the data before printing haha

Comment: Sorry, I was off. This issue still On?